# How to create an effective web crawler in php

Tags: php, web-crawler

I am trying to create a web crawler. I found a really useful website but there is a problem.
It only find links in one page, while I want to find all the link, sublink, in the entire website, not just one page. After research for the while, I read in some site who suggest to create loop function, call the procedure inside the procedure.

After I did that, another problem occur, there are too much repeated links and the php code become error because not enough memory allocated. I tried several method to get rid of repeated link, but none of it work. My best shot is using this array, the link which is not in the array will be kept, while the link which already in the array will be ignored. But so far, it is still no good.

Can anyone probably help me? Here is my code.

```
    ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
    include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

    $urlarray = array();
    $a=0;

    function crawl_page($target_url, $urlarray){

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    foreach($html->find('a') as $link)
    {   
        if (!in_array($link->href, $urlarray)) {
             $arraysize = sizeof($urlarray);
             echo $link->href."<br />";
             $urlarray[$arraysize] = $link->href;
             crawl_page($link->href, $urlarray);
          }
        }
     }

     $url[0]= "http://www.lazada.co.id";
     crawl_page("http://www.lazada.co.id", $url);
```

And the result is this:

( ! ) Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\testcrawler\simple_html_dom.php on line 555

UPDATE:

I have solved it. I found link somewhere in the stackoverflow who has the same problem. At there someone suggest not to use recursion model, but use queue model instead. So I modified my code to queue model and it worked. Now my web crawler is running well as I write this.

Comment: Have you tried using available classes that handle this sort of work? Goutte would be one (https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)

Comment: Not yet. I just tried simple_html_dom(). But like I said above, simple_html_dom only good for one page. Then I will try goutte first.

Comment: Try the library from spatie: https://github.com/spatie/crawler.

Comment: @RudyRaito Can you please provide us your solution to make helpful for others who are facing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Web Crawling is not only extracting data from a web page .. 
but as you mentioned in you question i guess that you just want to extract some elements from web pages

so, PHP has [phpQuery](https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery) library to interact web page extracting  .. it is not the only library in php but it is the most popular

i hope that help you

Answer (score -1):

Here is the full code of PHP Web Crawler with explanations, let's go:

```
    <?php
    // set user agent 
      ini_set('user_agent', 'NameOfAgent (http://www.example.net)');
    //initializing url to crawl
      $url = "http://www.example.net/somepage.html";
     //checking robots.txt and extracting more links, sublinks from url
 if(robots_allowed($url, "NameOfAgent")) {
        $input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
        $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
        if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
          foreach($matches as $match) {
            // $match[2] = link address it means that will show you link title
            // $match[3] = link text it means that will show you link title
          }
        }
      } else {
        die('Access denied by robots.txt');
      }
   
//function for extracting title, keywords, description from url
    function file_get_contents_curl($url)
    {
    $ch = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

                        $data = curl_exec($ch);
                            curl_close($ch);

                                return $data;
                                }

                                $html = file_get_contents_curl($url);

                                //parsing begins here:
                                $doc = new DOMDocument();
                                @$doc->loadHTML($html);
                                $nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');

                                //get and display what you need:
                                $title = $nodes->item(0)->nodeValue;


                       $metas = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');

                                for ($i = 0; $i < $metas->length; $i++)
                                {
                                    $meta = $metas->item($i);
                                        if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'description')
                                                $description = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                                                    if($meta->getAttribute('name') == 'keywords')
                                                            $keywords = $meta->getAttribute('content');
                                } 

}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please format your code. It's absolut horrible and not readable like this. Then add more comments to the code.

Comment: Man, I just fell for this thread to post as well, why did you necro a four year old thread?

Comment: Hi maio290, bro I'm a student and beginner in php and this code was running properly without dumping errors

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -1):

I guess nothing can beat the old [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) and [`substr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) combo when it comes to speed.

It's basically inconvenient, but I have written several crawlers using this approach and I doubt that it can technically go any faster than that in PHP.

Here is a brief example:

```
function extractVideoURL(&$html,$start)
{
    $value = strpos($html,'meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="',$start)+strlen('meta name="twitter:player:stream" content="');
    $end = strpos($html,'"',$value);
    $URL = substr($html,$value,$end-$value);
    return $URL;    
}
```

Also, the memory overhead is rather low since you don't parse the HTML into another structure.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. How does the given function crawl URLs from multiple pages?